# Using Google Analytics to track user profile data

Tags: google-analytics

We use Google Analytics on our Intranet. Each time a user goes on a page, at that point, we know all the information about them (we use SSO).

I would like to capture Department and Team (as examples) from their profile. Nothing that could uniquely identify the individual.

This *should* allow us to say that X people from department Y viewed page X or X people from team Y viewed page Z.

Is this possible, if so, what's the best way to go about doing it? We're using events for stuff like videos/forms but don't think it's useful here.

Would it be dimensions and metrics (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)

Comment: [Create and edit custom dimensions and metrics - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en)

Comment: Seconded - custom dimensions (none of your examples would need a custom metric). If you can get at the data with your JavaScript you can get it into GA.